# Log file is clobbered by the second run if I run my java application 2x in a row

Tags: logging, log4j

I would need your advice as I am not familiar with log4j. I have a java project using Maven.
My configuration allows me to have only one log file per day. 
So right now if I run my application 2x in a row, the log file is clobbered by the 2nd run.
I'll never have a log from the first run.
I would like to be able to get a new log file every time I run my application.

This is how I run my application via command line:

`java -cp .;MyProject.jar com.data.utils.project.main.Main > .\log\log_total_%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt`

It generates a log file named: `log_total_20170728.txt`

I have a log4j dependancy in my pom.xml file:

Below is my log4j.xml content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %C{2}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="log/log_total.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %C{2}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a new log file after every run, each log filename will have to be unique in some way so it doesn't get overwritten.  The easiest way is to add a timestamp to the log's filename.  The following modification adds hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to the log filename:

```
java -cp .;MyProject.jar com.data.utils.project.main.Main >
.\log\log_total_%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%.txt
```

The resulting log filename should look something like this:

```
log_total_20170728_15140437.txt
```